# Router buying advice

Tags: wireless-networking, router, performance

I am looking to buy a new router. The follow things are important

- Speed of data transferring across the network
- Dual Band? Is it possible to buy one which will transfer both N and G so older devices can connect? What should I look for to do so (what's it called)?
- Are some routers capable of having a larger, better, range? What should I look for in that case?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about shopping recommendations are considered off topic on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buying a router is like buying a PC, its all preference and choice.  Most router however are compatible with multi-transfer protocols, meaning that a wireless N will mostly likely also be G and maybe even A.  The range of the router can be a big thing, but the biggest thing with that is also where the router is placed.  If a router with the furthest range capabilities is behind a metal/concrete wall, you'll get a bad connection.  However a typical router placed in a well placed area, each device can be physically seen, then the connection will be better. With that said, buying a router that can change the antenna will help extend the range of the router.  You can buy a bigger antenna.  [Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/8-tips-to-boost-the-signal-from-your-wireless-router/) is a really good guide to extending the range of your router signal.

Personally I'm a fan of Linksys, but again it's all preference.  [This](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124190&nm_mc=OTC-Froogle&cm_mmc=OTC-Froogle-_-Network+-+Wireless+Routers-_-Linksys-_-33124190) is actually the router that I have at home, flashed to DD-WRT.  It does a wonderful job, and streaming HD content across the network works great, and I don't have very many issues with speed.  Do stay away at **ALL** costs from netgear.  I've had nothing but problems with them.

Comment: While I've been a fan of the WRT54G series myself, isn't it starting to age?

Comment: While it's getting outdated, it's very reliable, and works very fast for most uses.  I don't feel that for the average user and even most "experienced" users will need the ultra-fast speeds of newer routers.  Again though it's all left for preference and choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a [D-Link DIR-655](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=530), which supports both wireless N and G, includes a 4-port gigabit switch and has an excellent range, reaching anywhere in my house, including the back deck.  It's reasonably priced and I've been very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a site which provides some "non-trivial" reviews of routers I would suggest [SmallNetBuilder](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/).

You might also find their [How To Buy a Wireless Router: The Short Version](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30905-how-to-buy-a-wireless-router-short-version) article of some use. (If it's too simple minded for you, there is also a "longer" version. The link to it is included in the short article.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't go wrong with Linksys WRT54G. You can easily upgrade it with OpenWRT or DD-WRT firmware with great options, among them boost the signl strength and enhance security.